# Head tilt position ARKit - iOS

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

Is there a way to determine if the head position is tilted to the left or right or even centered using ARKit. Can we use `ARFaceAnchor`'s `leftEyeTransform` & `rightEyeTransform` to find the tilt position of user's head? Is there any better way to find this? I'm a starter in ARKit and SceneKit world, sorry if my question wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfaceanchor) states

> The inherited `transform` property describes the face’s current position
>   and orientation in world coordinates; that is, in a coordinate space
>   relative to that specified by the `worldAlignment` property of the
>   session configuration.

And so if you're using `ARWorldAlignmentGravity` or `ARWorldAlignmentGravityAndHeading` (« The coordinate system's y-axis is parallel to gravity ») you can determine whether the head is tilted or not.